# Cleaning up File-share server

Tags: powershell, script, disk-cleanup

I've been trying to make a PowerShell script that lists all files and folders, their created date and last accessed date, size in MB, and if possible the last person that accessed it, with an export to a CSV file.

I have tested a few scripts and even got help from the other post, but it does not pull all the files.

This is the script I am currently running:

```
 Get-ChildItem c:\Users\iceledon -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)} |
Export-Csv "C:\Users\iceledon\Desktop\files.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you can get from file properties. of the first file selected

```
# This is all you can get from file properties. of the first file selected
(Get-ChildItem 'd:\temp\*.txt')[0] | Select-Object -Property *

# Results

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp\1 passwordchangelog.txt
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\temp
PSChildName       : 1 passwordchangelog.txt
PSDrive           : D
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             D:\temp\1 passwordchangelog.txt
                    InternalName:     
                    OriginalFilename: 
                    FileVersion:      
                    FileDescription:  
                    Product:          
                    ProductVersion:   
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:         

BaseName          : 1 passwordchangelog
Target            : {}
LinkType          : 
Name              : 1 passwordchangelog.txt
Length            : 24
DirectoryName     : D:\temp
Directory         : D:\temp
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : D:\temp\1 passwordchangelog.txt
Extension         : .txt
CreationTime      : 10-Jul-18 16:30:22
CreationTimeUtc   : 10-Jul-18 23:30:22
LastAccessTime    : 10-Jul-18 16:30:22
LastAccessTimeUtc : 10-Jul-18 23:30:22
LastWriteTime     : 06-Jul-18 22:16:24
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 07-Jul-18 05:16:24
Attributes        : Archive
```

As you can see from the above properties on the file object. there is no info on who accessed it last.
Lastly you have to convert the length to KB,MB, etc.

So, you doing this...(just don't use the Format-Table for output.  This is just for the screen)

```
Get-ChildItem 'd:\temp' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)} `
| Select FullName,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,
    @{Name='Size(kb)';Expression={“{0:F2}” -f ($_.length/1KB)}},
    @{Name='Size(mb)';Expression={“{0:F2}” -f ($_.length/1MB)}} `
| Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime `
| Format-Table -AutoSize

FullName                                       CreationTime       LastAccessTime     Size(kb) Size(mb)
--------                                       ------------       --------------     -------- --------
D:\temp\4 passwordchangelog.txt                05-Jul-18 13:15:04 05-Jul-18 13:15:04 0.02     0.00    
D:\temp\1 passwordchangelog.txt                10-Jul-18 16:30:22 10-Jul-18 16:30:22 0.02     0.00    
D:\temp\10 passwordchangelog.txt               10-Jul-18 16:30:26 10-Jul-18 16:30:26 0.02     0.00 
...
```

What do you mean by...

> but it does not pull all the files.

GCI will all files you ask of it as long as you have the permissions to do so.
If you filter in anyway, that is all that will be returned.

AddDays(-365)

This means, only give me files older than. Thus anything not older than, you will not get, by design.